# Where is UIView.init() documented?

Tags: ios, swift

In the folowing example:

```
import UIKit

class MyView: UIView
{
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
       super.init(frame: frame)
       print ("...init with frame")
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        print("...init with coder")
    }
}
```

.......

```
 let var = MyView() //  "...init with frame" gets printed
```

So it seems `MyView()` calls `UIView.init()` which in turn calls `init(frame: CGRect)`.
However according to the [UIView documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/initWithFrame:) there is only a init(frame:) (and (init:coder)).

According to the [documenation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/init)  for NSObject. init()

> does no initialization; it simply returns self.

So there must be a `UIView.init()` that overrides `NSObject.init()` and in turn calls `init(frame:)`. But this `UIView.init()` isn't documented? Or am I missing this documentation?

Answer (score 6):

I have found no documentation for `UIView.init`, but `UIView.init` does exist.  If you set a breakpoint at your `print ("...init with frame")`, you will see the call to `[UIView init]` in the *Debug Navigator*.  The assembly code clearly shows it calling `objc_msgSend` to `initWithFrame:` using `CGRectZero` as the frame:

```
UIKit`-[UIView init]:
    0x10b3ba160 <+0>:  pushq  %rbp
    0x10b3ba161 <+1>:  movq   %rsp, %rbp
    0x10b3ba164 <+4>:  subq   $0x20, %rsp
    0x10b3ba168 <+8>:  movq   0xc52f71(%rip), %rsi      ; "initWithFrame:"
    0x10b3ba16f <+15>: movq   0xcd5f72(%rip), %rax      ; (void *)0x000000010f732690: CGRectZero
    0x10b3ba176 <+22>: movq   0x18(%rax), %rcx
    0x10b3ba17a <+26>: movq   %rcx, 0x18(%rsp)
    0x10b3ba17f <+31>: movq   0x10(%rax), %rcx
    0x10b3ba183 <+35>: movq   %rcx, 0x10(%rsp)
    0x10b3ba188 <+40>: movq   (%rax), %rcx
    0x10b3ba18b <+43>: movq   0x8(%rax), %rax
    0x10b3ba18f <+47>: movq   %rax, 0x8(%rsp)
    0x10b3ba194 <+52>: movq   %rcx, (%rsp)
    0x10b3ba198 <+56>: callq  *0xcd7042(%rip)           ; (void *)0x000000010c8b9800: objc_msgSend
    0x10b3ba19e <+62>: addq   $0x20, %rsp
    0x10b3ba1a2 <+66>: popq   %rbp
    0x10b3ba1a3 <+67>: retq
```

Comment: Thanks. That's what it looked like to me too. It seems like just missing documentation, then I suppose. Strange for an initializer of one of the most common classes in iOS  not to be documented!

Comment: I suspect Apple really wants to encourage the use of the the other initializers.  The call tree is shorter if you just use `MyView(frame: CGRectZero)`.

Answer (score 2):

`UIView.init()` exists — however, it's not publicly declared because that declaration is inherited from the `NSObject` class.

In neither Swift nor ObjC-bridged-to-Swift does a class have to declare as public API the methods/properties it inherits from a superclass or includes by conforming to a protocol. Inheritance or protocol adoption means that the class supports those methods/properties, but it doesn't tell you anything about what the class' implementation of them *does*. For that you have to read documentation... carefully.

Expanding a bit on the `NSObject.init()` [doc](https://developer.apple.com/reference/objectivec/nsobject/1418641-init) you quoted (with some editing for emphasis):

> Implemented by subclasses to initialize a new object (the receiver) immediately after memory for it has been allocated.
>
> The `init()` method ***defined in the `NSObject` class*** does no initialization... (1)
>
> In a custom implementation of this method, you must invoke `super`’s initializer then initialize and return the new object... (2)

This could probably be clearer ([I recommend filing a bug against the documentation so Apple knows to improve it](http://bugreport.apple.com)), so a quick translation:

1. In a "bare" `NSObject` instance, `init()` does nothing. That is, the method is there purely for subclassing.
2. Subclasses are expected to invoke `super` and perform their own initialization. Where you see "custom" and "you" here, read it as the implementor of a subclass — that, is, the "you" here applies equally to you, the third-party developer creating new classes in your app, and to the authors of other Apple classes that subclass `NSObject`. (You know, just about all of them.)

---

The way Apple's API documentation seems to work, they only have docs at the method level for methods that are declared by a class — there aren't docs on `UIView` for all the hundreds of methods that it inherits from all of its superclasses, nor on each of the many `UIView` subclasses for all of the methods they inherit from `UIView`.

As noted in other answers, the no-args initializer for `UIView` is equivalent to using `init(frame:)` and passing `CGRect.zero`. Even though Apple's docs don't have a place to attach descriptions to `UIView.init()`, it'd probably be helpful for them to discuss the effects of inherited initializers somewhere else. (Maybe in the [`UIView` class overview](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiview)?) That's probably worth [filing another documentation bug.](http://bugreport.apple.com)

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
The only part of your post which directly addresses my question is however: 

"The way Apple's API documentation seems to work..inherit from UIView."

Is this indeed how Apples documentation works in general? If so then it shouldn't (imo). I filed a bug about this - thanks for the suggestion. All overriden methods (publically) callable on an an object should be documented. What eg no arg UiView.init() now (seems) to do is liable to change without notice, breaking existing code, if its not at least clearly documented.

Comment: @rickster How is it that UIView inherits an initializer from NSObject? Since UIView defines its own designated initializers the initializer inheritance is blocked, yes?

Comment: @RobertVaessen Initializers are methods, so subclasses always inherit them just like they do other methods or properties. A subclass can change which initializers are designated initializers, but that doesn't prevent other initializers from being inherited.

Comment: Shouldn't UIView actually override init() to be able to call init(frame:) passing CGRect.zero?

Answer (score 0):

If you call MyView() in swift. It means it call default constructor i.e init is called. If you want to call initWithFrame as in  objective c then you have to call constructor like MyView(frame:CGRect). And for detail you must follow apple documentation.

Comment: Thanks but this is not what I asked.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html.