# Where does UIView.init() come from?

Tags: ios, swift

I have read [elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38930691/where-is-uiview-init-documented) on Stack Overflow that UIView inherits init() from NSObject. However, this does not make sense. Since UIView defines its own designated initializers, the initializer inheritance should be blocked. Or, is that rule altered when a swift class inherits from an objective-c class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep in mind that UIView is an Objective-C class, and Objective-C is not Swift. None of the rules about designated and convenience initializers and the rules of their inheritance exist in Objective-C — a fact that can sometimes cause significant trouble when using those classes in Swift. That said, in effect, UIView's `init()` is a convenience initializer that calls `init(frame: .zero)`.

Comment: "in effect"? Can you say precisely where UIView's init() method is defined?

Comment: Well, I'm not sure what you think you mean by that. As you said, it is inherited from NSObject, the superclass — because in Objective-C, that sort of thing is just fine. But my "in effect" tells you how to understand what happens when you actually _call_ this method. Indeed, by appropriate placement of symbolic breakpoints, you can discover that UIView's `init` does in fact call `initWithFrame:` with a value of CGRectZero. Keep in mind that Swift is very new, whereas Cocoa — and a lot of us — have been at this for much longer.

Comment: Matt, First; thanks! My thinking about the rules for inheritance between UIView and NSObject was faulty - they are both, as you pointed out, objective-c classes. That being said: UIView must somewhere override NSObject's init() method so as to be able to call init(frame: .zero), yes? Why do we not see this override in the docs? An oversight?

Comment: No, because the docs largely "think" in Objective-C still. And in Objective-C, initializers are just inherited like any other method. So there is no need to call out specially the fact that UIView has an `init()` method. And Objective-C has no special "override" marker either. And remember, all _you_ are seeing is the docs and the headers; you cannot see Cocoa's actual _code_.

Comment: Okay. So, my take away is that, regarding the documentation of objective-c classes, we have no way of knowing whether or not a subclass reimplements (overrides) a base classes methods. Thanks again, Matt.

Comment: "regarding the documentation of objective-c classes, we have no way of knowing whether or not a subclass reimplements (overrides) a base classes methods" I think that's a fair assessment. And it can be mighty confusing. For example, how do you turn an NSArray into an NSMutableArray? You call NSMutableArray's `initWithArray:` — which is not documented under NSMutableArray, but under its superclass, NSArray!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132221/discussion-between-robert-vaessen-and-matt).